# Neo4j count based on single relationship to node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to find all persons who participated in all specified movies, for example in 2 movies: "The Terminator", "True Lies"

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (t:Title)-[:ACTS_IN]-(p:Principal)-[:ACTS_BY]->(n:Name) 
WHERE t.originalTitle IN ["The Terminator", "True Lies"] 
WITH n, collect(n) as names 
WHERE SIZE(names) >= 2 
RETURN n.primaryName
```

which works fine if every person participated (`:ACTS_BY` relationship) only once in every movie. But according to my database schema design, every person can have 0-N `:ACTS_BY` relationships between Principal and Name nodes(for example the same person can be producer and actor of the movie at the same time).

The issue is that the mentioned Cypher query will also return the person(`Name` node) in case that person participated 2+ times in one movie and 0 times in another but I only need to return the `Name` node in case the person participated in each movie.

Please help to improve the query in order to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you'll want to get distinct values of `t, p, n` to weed out the duplicates, and only then do a count:

```
MATCH (t:Title)-[:ACTS_IN]-(p:Principal)-[:ACTS_BY]->(n:Name) 
WHERE t.originalTitle IN ["The Terminator", "True Lies"] 
WITH DISTINCT t, p, n
WITH n, count(n) as occurrences 
WHERE occurrences >= 2 
RETURN n.primaryName
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still returns `James Cameron` in case of the following condition `IN ["The Terminator", "SOME_FREAKY_NAME"]` but I don't have the movie `SOME_FREAKY_NAME` in the database and in this case I expect the empty result

Comment: I think this is because of 4 distinct `p` for `James Cameron` which the following query returns `MATCH (t:Title)-[:ACTS_IN]-(p:Principal)-[:ACTS_BY]->(n:Name) WHERE t.originalTitle IN ["The Terminator"] AND n.primaryName="James Cameron" RETURN DISTINCT p`

Comment: How to properly take into account in the query the only 1 `(p:Principal)` for `(t:Title)` and `(n:Name)` pair?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following, can you add the Cypher for recreating the relevant part of your graph so I can run a few tests?

Comment: Thanks, I think I found the issue! I have more than one "The Terminator" entry in the DB... like a movie, video game and so on